# how to use outlook rest calendar api with java

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

Hi I am trying to run the calendar api by google to read/write to my calendar initially and then implement a system to add events asynchronously to other users calendars once an even gets added to my application. As part of this I was trying to understand how to work with google calendar api and outlook rest calendar api. I was able to add the events to other users calendars in google calendar,however unable to figure out how to do it using java and outlook rest api. How to ensure my application adds an event to outlook calendar once an event is added to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use the following link to get the required functionality..i have tried it and its working for me.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java